# Ionic 3 problemas com get em estorage

Tags: json, ionic, ionic3

Estou com o seguinte problema.

```js
  apelidoCidade(){
  let cidade =  this.storage.get('apelidocidade').then(res => console.log(res));
   
     return cidade;
   
  }
  getbanner(){
   
    let url = 'http://localhost/'+  this.apelidoCidade() +'/index.php?component=json&action=bannerinicio';
    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(url);
    data.subscribe(result => {
    this.banners = result;  
   
     
    });
  }
```

Ele me retorna a cidade no console log. Mas me dar o seguinte erro no console

:8100/#/home:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/[object%20Promise]/index.php?component=json&action=bannerinicio' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Como eu consigo resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Bem, há pelo menos 2 erros.

1 - Você está fazendo uma requisição para um servidor local que não está com o CORS habilitado. [Você pode ver mais sobre CORS aqui](https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors). Resumindo, aplicativos em ionic são uma webview. Quando seu aplicativo tenta acessar dados de algum lugar, é como se seu navegador estivesse em um site (localhost:8100) tentando acessar dados de outro site (localhost:80). Isso por padrão é bloqueado, pois pode ser um código malicioso que está tentando obter informações de um site sem o conhecimento do usuário.

Para resolver esse problema, você tem 2 opções: preparar seu servidor para liberar o CORS de requisições que vierem do seu aplicativo ou fazer requisições utilizando o http plugin que simula um dispositivo real nas chamadas http. [Ambas soluções descritas aqui.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors#solutions-for-cors-errors)

2 - O outro problema é que sua função "apelidoCidade()" retorna uma Promise, e você não está esperando ela ser resolvida antes de chamar a requisição http. Nesse caso, o valor retornado quando você chama "this.apelidoCidade()" não é a cidade, pois a Promise ainda não terminou de executar. Você poderia mudar a função para algo assim:

```
apelidoCidade(){
     this.storage.get('apelidocidade').then(res => {
     console.log(res);
     return res;
    });
```

Para mais clareza sobre Promise, pode ir [nesse link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gMOWEjPFaI)